# Javascript: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a js file called table_java.js and I'm trying to get it to work in my HTML file test.html.
I keep getting the error, `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <` I believe the problem is that the js file is being read as a text file. But I'm not sure if that is the problem / have no idea how to fix it. Any help/ advice would be appreciated.

Here is table_java.js

```
<script type ="text/javascript">
<!--
        $(document).ready( function () {

                // Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
                $('#POGs_table tfoot th').each( function () {
                    var title = $(this).text();
                    $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
                } );

            var table = $('#POGs_table').DataTable( {
                "lengthMenu": [[10, 25, 50, -1], [10, 25, 50, "All"]],
                "order": [[0,"asc"]],
                "aoColumnDefs": [ { "sSortDataType": "numeric", "aTargets": [3,4,5] } ]
            } );


                // Apply the search
                table.columns().every( function () {
                    var that = this;

                    $( 'input', this.footer() ).on( 'keyup change', function () {
                            if ( that.search() !== this.value ) {
                                that
                                        .search( this.value )
                                        .draw();
                            }
                    });
                });
            //Hide/Show function
            $('a.showHideColumn').on('click', function() {

                var tableColumn = table.column($(this).attr('data-columnindex'));
                tableColumn.visible(!tableColumn.visible());
            });
        });
-->
</script>
```

Here is the head section of test.html

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Phage Orthologous Groups</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="krist_datatables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="table_try.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="table_java.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: You don't need `<!--` and `-->` and `script` tags in your script

Answer (score 0):

remove tags  from table_java.js, it's already JS script

Comment: Also remove <!-- at the start and --> at the end. These are used for HTML comments.

Answer (score 0):

`-->` is not valid javascript. It must be escaped: `//-->`.

And these days you do NOT need the html comments inside script blocks. Any still using a browser so ancient to not support `<script>` is a dinosaur you do NOT need to worry about supporting.